# How can I open two URLs with a five second delay?

Tags: javascript

I have the below javascript code. Basically what I want to do is when a user is clicking on the hyperlink, I want to open a new tab, call https://somesite.com/logout, first, wait 5 seconds and then call https://www.somesite.com

This is possible to do? If so, what changes can I make to this code to get that done?

```
script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
document.getElementById("mySite").onclick = function() {myFunction()};

function myFunction() {
    //your code goes here
  var win1= window.open("https://somesite.com/logout");
   win1.close();
}
};
</script>

<a href='https://www.somesite.com' target='_blank' id='mysite'>Click Here</a>
```

Comment: [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)

Answer (score 1):

```
window.onload = function() {
document.getElementById("mysite").onclick = function() {myFunction()};

function myFunction() {
    //your code goes here
  var win1= window.open("https://somesite.com/logout");
   win1.close();
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    window.open("https://somesite.com");
  }, 5000);
}
};
```

getElementById is case sensitive, so be sure to use "mysite". You can set a timeout to open a window after 5000ms (5 seconds).

Also, be aware that browsers will typically block popups by default.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `window.setTimeout(window.location.reload(), 5000)` after close()